# Extract bold words in string

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel cell with text. Some words are bolded. Those words are keywords and should be extracted to another cell in the row for identification of the keywords.

Example:

**Text in Cell:**

> I want to use **Google** **Maps** for **route** informations

**Output:**

> Google; Maps; route;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use this UDF to produce same result. Please enter below code in module.

```
 Public Function findAllBold(ByVal rngText As Range) As String
    Dim theCell As Range
    Set theCell = rngText.Cells(1, 1)

    For i = 1 To Len(theCell.Value)       
        If theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then          
            If theCell.Characters(i + 1, 1).Text = " " Then
                theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text & ", "
                Else
                theChar = theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
            End If
            Results = Results & theChar
        End If
   Next i
   findAllBold = Results
End Function
```

Now you can use newly created function to return bold values from any cell.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this macro. Works like a charm, too :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim str As String, strBold As String
    Dim isBold As Boolean
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")    'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
    isBold = False

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'last row with data in Column A
        For Each cel In .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Cells      'loop through each cell in Column A
            strBold = ""
            For i = 1 To Len(cel.Value)
                If cel.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Bold = True Then 'check if character is bold
                    isBold = True
                    str = Mid(cel.Value, i, 1)
                    If cel.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Text = " " Then  'check for space
                        strBold = strBold & "; "
                        isBold = False
                    Else
                        strBold = strBold & str
                    End If

                Else
                    If isBold Then
                        strBold = strBold & "; "
                        isBold = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            cel.Offset(0, 1) = strBold
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Derived this code from [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/595012-extract-bold-text-from-cell.html).

Comment: @NikolaosPolygenis - Did you try executing above code?

Comment: yes, and works fine( with the.Font.Bold = True ).The previous with the Font.FontStyle = "Bold" delivers no text in the cel.Offset(0, 1).

Comment: @NikolaosPolygenis - I tested code before posting and all works fine even with `Font.FontStyle = "Bold"` though using `.Font.Bold = True` is better. Secondly, multiple variables can be declared in the same line separated by `,` so declaration of variables were not wrong, try it.

Comment: For the declaration you have right, in my comments, i write you cant declare for ex: dim str,strbold as string, but you write dim str as string,strbold as string which is accepted...I'm sorry.

Comment: @NikolaosPolygenis - Obviously using .Font.Bold = True is better, by the way nice find why it was not working.

Comment: I found why the Font.FontStyle = "Bold" didn't work in my tests...it didn't work because it takes, for example, the word "Bold", from the region settings of excel, in my case takes the word "Εντονα", which is the Bold in Greek. It is safe to use.Font.Bold = True to avoid the above.

Comment: Works like a charm :-) Thank you so much!